# Upload PHAsset from iCloud (i.e. which is not present on the local device )

Tags: ios, upload, icloud, phasset

I want to upload a PHAsset to the server. Now my PHAsset can be a photo or a video. I am able to do it successfully for the PHAssets present on the local device. But what if the PHAsset is not on the local device and instead present on the iCloud.

**Can we upload directly from the iCloud to the server or do we have to first download to the local device and then to upload operation to the server.**

Also, I would be grateful if someone could tell how to do this.

---

Update: when we allow the network access to download the image form the iCloud I get this below error.

```
{

    PHImageErrorKey = "Error Domain=CloudPhotoLibraryErrorDomain Code=1000 \"Error fetching asset with identifier: AUXxudUWWzHheX1dXyRDgXpZN5ty\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Error fetching asset with identifier: AUXxudUWWzHheX1dXyRDgXpZN5ty, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb00a5e9480 {Error Domain=CKErrorDomain Code=6 \"Fetching asset failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Fetching asset failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb00a511600 {Error Domain=CKInternalErrorDomain Code=2022 \"Fetching asset failed\" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=Fetching asset failed, NSUnderlyingError=0x7fb00a5b6fc0 {Error Domain=com.apple.mmcs Code=16 \"(null)\"}}}}}}";

    PHImageResultDeliveredImageFormatKey = 0;

    PHImageResultIsInCloudKey = 1;

    PHImageResultWantedImageFormatKey = 20002;

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should download the asset inside your mobile app and then upload to your server. I don't think it's possible to upload directly from iCloud because of Sandboxing and other privacy & security rules.

If you use `PHCachingImageManager` & `requestImageForAsset`, you should specify special option `networkAccessAllowed` for `PHImageRequestOptions` which is allow iCloud to fetch data as described in [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/reference/photos/phassetresourcerequestoptions/1616275-networkaccessallowed):

> If YES, and the requested resource data is not stored on the local device, Photos downloads that data from iCloud.
>
> > **NOTE**: You should enable iCloud entitlement with iCloud Documents service and setup default container. See more details here [Enabling CloudKit in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html). As I can see, it's required when you use `networkAccessAllowed = true`

For example, you can setup options for your asset manager like this:

```
PHImageRequestOptions *requestOptions = [PHImageRequestOptions new];
requestOptions.synchronous = NO;
requestOptions.resizeMode = PHImageRequestOptionsResizeModeFast;
requestOptions.deliveryMode = PHImageRequestOptionsDeliveryModeHighQualityFormat;
requestOptions.networkAccessAllowed = YES;
```

and then request data

```
[self.cachingImageManager requestImageForAsset:asset targetSize:PHImageManagerMaximumSize contentMode:PHImageContentModeDefault options:requestOptions resultHandler:^(UIImage * _Nullable resultImage, NSDictionary * _Nullable info) {
...
}];
```

In this case, you'll see how iCloud fetch data inside document picker before make a call to `resultHandler` where you can handle the requested asset.

Comment: Your thoughts on downloading the asset first and then uploading to the server are very helpful. I tried to get the image like this but I get the error 'Fetching asset failed'. See the updated question.

Comment: Does the request for the asset fails because the app doesn't have access to the iCloud? I have not enrolled in the Apple developer program.

Comment: Yes. You should enable iCloud entitlement with iCloud Documents service and setup default container. See more details here [Enabling CloudKit in Your App](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DataManagement/Conceptual/CloudKitQuickStart/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit/EnablingiCloudandConfiguringCloudKit.html). 

As I can see, it's required when you use `networkAccessAllowed = true`.

Comment: And, by the way, [How-To: Create a free Apple developer account for sideloading apps](https://9to5mac.com/2016/03/27/how-to-create-free-apple-developer-account-sideload-apps/).

Comment: Thanks, I already have it. But to use iCloud I guess I need to enroll and pay the fee for the Apple developer program.

Comment: Check Here: [Apple app capabilities](https://developer.apple.com/support/app-capabilities/)

Comment: Hm, I see. But apparently, this is the only option to fetch data from iCloud.