# Is CloudKit required for fetching user selected images?

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, icloud, cloudkit

I am trying to get the URL of the user selected images. I managed to get it when the image is stored locally in the device. However, am still researching on how to get the images path that are stored in the iCloud.

I found a library called `CloudKit` that is used to upload and download images but from what I also found is that it is like the old Parse, which gives us storage online "Database" to store the images and then retrieve them from there. But in my case I want to download the image that is stored in the user's iCloud.

My question is, should I enable the `CloudKit` in order to retrieve the user chosen images from iCloud? or is `CloudKit` meant for different usage? (e.g. cloud database)

**NOTE**: The comments of the answer [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40749624/upload-phasset-from-icloud-i-e-which-is-not-present-on-the-local-device) confused me.

Comment: If you want to use CloudKit than you'll have to enable it. You could also look into firebase which is also a backend in which you can store this sort of data, although CloudKit is easier if your new too all this I think.

Answer (score 0):

CloudKit provides an iCloud hosted database. You *can* store and retrieve images there but it is not what you need to access existing images on a user's iCloud photo album. You need to use the [Photos Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/photos) for that.

Comment: can you help me with the classes I should use? I tried to use "PHImageManager.default().requestImageData()" passing the PHAsset image, and inside it I used "let options = PHAssetResourceRequestOptions" "options.isNetworkAccessAllowed" but I still can only retrieve local images path. If you have experience with this. Can you please advice me if I am using the correct classes or I should another class to download the metadata?

Comment: @Source Sorry, I know CloudKit but not Photos. I would recommend asking that as a separate question, don't forget to include your code and full details of why it is not working for you.